# Find the icon for a specific file type

Tags: gnome

Is there any way to find the icon for a specific file type? I'd like to write a shell script that returns the location of the image file, or icon, for a specific file type.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you could can get the icon with something like:

```
>>> from gi.repository import Gio
>>> Gio.content_type_get_icon('text/python')
<ThemedIcon object at 0xb5d61324 (GThemedIcon at 0xa372590)>
```

Comment: How can I find the name and location of the icon image's file? I don't see any file names being printed here.